# insert text in html tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following code in cshtml page:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="..." >Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="..." >Link2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I want to change class of a tag when some condition is true.
I tried this, but it does not work:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li 
    <script> if (..condition..) 
      document.write(" class = \"newclass\"");
    </script>
  ><a href="..." >Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="..." >Link2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Could you please suggest the way to do it?

Thanks,
Zhenya

Comment: this is not a valid HTML syntax .

Comment: What is the condition that needs to be met? Should the class apply to all `li` elements under menu or a specific `li` element? If a specific one, which element?

Comment: `document.write` writes to the output... and not to the markup itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the `li` an ID as shown below:

```
 <li id="list"><a href="..." >Link1</a></li>
 <li><a href="..." >Link2</a></li>
```

Then in your JavaScript try:

```
if (condition) {
   var element = document.getElementById("list");
   element.className = "newclass";
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bVGFP/

Comment: I just edited the variable reference when setting the `className` property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `document.innerHTML`  because `document.write` need the reload page.

```
<ul id="menu">
                <li  
                    //This is not valid syntax
                    <script> if (..condition..) 
                                document.write(" class = \"newclass\"");
                    </script>
                   ><a href="..." >Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="..." >Link2</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Then for you case, I suggest for you

```
    <ul id="menu">
                    <li id="po"><a href="..." >Link1</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="..." >Link2</a></li>
                </ul>

<script>
document.getElementById("po").className = "newclass";
                        </script>
```

Comment: *"`document.write` need the reload page"* That's correct. Once the document was completely parsed, `documen.write` will **overwrite** the whole document, it won't reload the page. However using `document.write` while the document is still being parsed is perfectly fine (theoretically). It will just insert the data where it is called. The problem here is that the OP tried to use `<script>` tags inside an opening tag of another element which is simply invalid HTML. Using `document.write` is not the problem, although using it is not very good either.

Comment: Thx DArren for the suggst and @FelixKling for the best suggest.
And I not know if I have to remove my answer because this will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Please give an id to the li

`<li id="test"></li>` access the `<li>` by id

```
$("#test").addClass("classname");
```

Comment: What is `$` here? It's not a native DOM or JavaScript function.